# Custom product attributes behaviour magento

Tags: magento

I will be very direct..
[Reference Ecommerce Website](http://www.manndola.com/new-arrivals-sarees-salwar-kameez/splendid-velvet-print-palazzo-style-suit-with-chiffon-print-dupatta-jinaam-regal-scarlet-8471)

There is a custom stitching options menu on the product description page.
1. Unstitched
2. Standard Measurements
3. Custom measurements

On standard and custom measurements, drop downs and a popup opens respectively, whose details goes on further with the added product.

How can i implement the same product options menu in magento ?

Comment: Do you want to code this yourself?

Answer (score 0):

it's easy the reference site is a magento, an that are a bundle product

the only thing you need create a new product with the options.

UPDATE for @Enigmativity

in the official webside of Magento say:

"A **bundle** is a “build your own,” customizable product. Each item in a bundle can be based on one of the following product types:

- Simple Product
- Virtual Product

**OpenStep 1:   Create the Bundle Product**

1. On the Admin menu, select Catalog > Manage Products. Then, click the Add Product button.
2. In the Create Product Settings section, select the Attribute Set for the product.
3. In the Create Product Settings section, do the following:

   a.  Accept the “default” Attribute Set, or select another.

   b.  Set Product Type to “Bundle Product.” Then, click the Continue button.

**Step 2: Complete the Product Information**

1. Complete the product information as you would for a simple product, with the exception of the following:

   a.  On the General tab, set both the SKU and Weight fields to one of the     following:

   Dynamic

   Fixed

If using a fixed SKU or Weight, enter the actual value in the field to the right.

Dynamic SKU and Weight

b.  On the Prices tab, set Price to one of the following:

Dynamic

Fixed

If using a fixed price, enter the actual value in the field to the right.

Minimum Advertised Price (MAP) is not available for Bundle products with dynamic pricing.

Dynamic Price

c.  Then, set Price View to one of the following:

As Low as

Price Range

2. Click the Save and Continue Edit button.

**Step 3: Add Bundle Items**

1. In the Product Information panel on the left, select the last option, Bundle Items.
2. Then in the Shipment section, set Ship Bundle Items to one of the following:
   Together
   Separately

Shipment

3. In the Bundle Items section, click the Add New Option button.
4. In the Default Title box, enter a label for the bundle item, as you want it to appear on the Customize Product page. Then, do the following:

Bundle Items

a.  Set Input Type to one of the following:

Drop-down

Radio Buttons

Checkbox

Multiple Select

b.  Set Is Required as needed.

c.  In the Position field, enter the order that you want this item listed in relation to other items included in the bundle.

5. Click the Add Selection button. Then, do the following:

Select Products

a.  Click the Reset Filter button to display the unfiltered list of products.

b.  Select the checkbox of each product that you want to include in this item.

c.  In the Qty to Add column, enter the quantity of each item to be included.

6. Click the Add Selected Product(s) to Option button. When the items appear in the Bundle Items list, do the following:

a.  Set User Defined Qty to one of the following:
Yes

Displays an input box so the customer can change the quantity.

No

Prevents the customer from changing the default quantity.

b.  Enter a number in the Position column of each item to determine its place in relation to other items.
c.  To make an item the default selection, select the Default option of the item to be pre-selected in the form.

Bundle Items
7.  Repeat steps 3-7 for each bundle item you want to include.
8.  When complete, click the Save button to save the bundle product.

"

reference : http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-bundle.html

Comment: Please don't link to external sites as your answer. The link could become broken or out-of-date. You should have a fully standalone answer on SO and only provide the link for further reading.

Comment: @Enigmativity and you for that put  a -1? when the response is valid and I put the link to the official webside of magento, only to explain what is a bundle product, I not create that, is a normal fuction to the systmem so I put the official link of my reference.

Comment: Yes, link-only answers are not appropriate - so they get a down-vote. Stack Overflow wants every answer to be valid for all time, so if Magento decide to update their site and break your link then your answer would also be broken. But you've fixed it. I've up-voted. Thanks.